# insert new doc via autoform hooks call meteor method

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I want to insert a new document into db using autoform. Autoform hook calls a meteor method on server to insert the document.

I have this in template...

```
{{#autoForm collection="Reports" id="addReport" type="insert"}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            {{> afQuickField name='hours'}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light modal-action modal-close"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Then...

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    addReport: {
        onSubmit: function(insertDoc) {
            Meteor.call('addReport', insertDoc, function(error, result) {
                if (error) alert(error.reason);
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

then the method on server...

```
Meteor.methods({
    addReport: function(insertDoc) {   
        var report = _.extend(insertDoc, {
            userId: Meteor.userId(),
        });
        return Reports.insert(report);
    }
});
```

I have a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields in collection, but they all have autoValue thus, I believe no need to do insertion from client or in the meteor method.

So collection with schema looks like this:

```
Reports = new Meteor.Collection('reports');

Reports.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    hours: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Number of hours",
        decimal: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created Date",
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return new Date;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
        },
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isUpdate) {
                return new Date()
            }
        },
        denyInsert: true,
        optional: true
    },
    "userId": {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden",
        }
    },
}));
```

When i run meteor, form displays, but submit does nothing. No visual cue as to if any error. No error message in both client and server console.

what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Is this in a modal? Does it work outside the modal?

Comment: @AutumnLeonard nope. its not in a modal.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd add some console logs along the way to see what is getting properly called.

Comment: I added a console log to the method call to know when it gets fired. It doesn't. Ooh and that modal class on there, its to close a modal action caused by something else.

Comment: Are you submitting with that "save" button? Try adding `type="submit"` to it.

Comment: With `type=submit`, didn't work. Added console logs to method call and the server method itself. none seems to fire. Autoform doesn't seem to be calling the hook

Answer (score 4):

Since `@Cristo GQ` got it right, I just want to make sure the answer is clear enough for future visitors of this thread

---

The `onSubmit` *hook* will be used **only** for autoForms **with** `type='normal'` or **without any** `type=` at all

---

On another note, the `before.insert` *hook* is just for `type='insert'` And there is no `before.normal` *hook*
This mean that when using the `onSubmit` *hook*, we have to do any "before work" (like adding *currentUser* to the doc) inside the `onSubmit` itself.

Answer (score 2):

aldeed/meteor-autoform documentation:

```
  // Called when form does not have a `type` attribute
  onSubmit: function(insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
     Meteor.call()...
  }
```

I'm following discovermeteor book, and I'm trying to use some methods of the book, but using the meteor-autoform package.

post_submit.html

```
<template name="postSubmit">

    {{#autoForm collection="Posts" id="insertPost"}} <-- no type

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    {{> afQuickField name='title' class='title form-control'}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    {{> afQuickField name='description' class='description form-control'}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary"/>

    {{/autoForm}}

</template>
```

post_submit.js

```
var postSubmitHook = {

    onSubmit: function(insertDoc){
        Meteor.call('postInsert', insertDoc, function(error, result) {

            if (error){
                Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
                $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
                return;
            }

            Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
        });
        return false;
    }
};

AutoForm.addHooks('insertPost', postSubmitHook);
```